# How to make octave configure detect Qt in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: octave, gnu

How to install GNU Octave 4.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the required Qt packages in their standard locations, then AFAIK no special steps are required to make the Octave 4.0.0 configuration script detect them.

According to the INSTALL.OCTAVE file provided with the source distribution, the required Qt components are:

```
Qt
     GUI and utility libraries ().  Qt is required for building the GUI.
     It is a large framework, but the only components required are the
     GUI, core, and network modules.
```

on Ubuntu, you can obtain these libraries and their header files by installing the `libqt4-dev` development package.